# SWT Horizontal line after Text fully expanded

Tags: java, swt, label

I'm trying to display a history in a Textfield in SWT.

The history generates a new shell which has two Composites. The first displays the Header part which contains the Label "History" and a horizontal line underneath. The second is Footer part which display the actual data. This works, but the horizontal line is not expanded (i.e.: "filled") throughout the available horizontal space (i.e.: until the Composite "end").

```
               public void mouseDown(final MouseEvent e) {
            findSegmentText.setText("");
            if(0 == lastSegmentIds.size()) return;
            if(disableToolTipsButton.getSelection()) return; // context help is not desired

            if(null != popupShell) popupShell.dispose();

            popupShell = new Shell(Display.getDefault(), SWT.BORDER | SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.MODELESS);
            //popupShell.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
            popupShell.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, false));

            /* Header */
            compositeSearchSegments1 = new Composite(popupShell, SWT.NONE);
            compositeSearchSegments1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
            compositeSearchSegments1.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(1, false));


            /* Footer */
            compositeSearchSegments2 = new Composite(popupShell, SWT.NONE);
            compositeSearchSegments2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
            compositeSearchSegments2.setLayout(createNoMarginLayout(2, false));

              Label history  = new Label(compositeSearchSegments1, SWT.NONE);
              history.setText("History");

              Label line1  = new Label(compositeSearchSegments1,  SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.SHADOW_OUT | SWT.HORIZONTAL);

            for(int i = lastSegmentIds.size()-1 ; i>=0;i--) { // iterate backwards, higher indexes have newer selected links

                final String lastSegmentId  = lastSegmentIds.get(i);


                l.setText(lastSegmentId);
                Button b = new Button(compositeSearchSegments2, SWT.NONE); 

                b.setVisible(true);
                b.setText(">>");
                b.setSize(10,10);


                b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                        findSegmentText.setText(lastSegmentId);
                        searchAndDisplayLink(Long.decode(findSegmentText.getText()));
                    }
                });
            }

                   Point point = optionsComposite.toDisplay(e.x + optionsComposite.getBounds().x +findSegmentText.getLocation().x, e.y + optionsComposite.getBounds().y+findSegmentText.getLocation().y );
            popupShell.setLocation(point.x-125, point.y-10);
            popupShell.pack();
            popupShell.open();
            findSegmentText.setFocus();

        }
```

Which produces the result:
[image]

I would like to expand the line to fill the available horizontal space. What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `GridLayout`, adding a `GridData` to the separator `Label` does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Label first = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    first.setText("short");

    Label separator = new Label(shell, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.SHADOW_OUT | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    separator.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    Label second = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    second.setText("looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong");

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]